# HTTP Authentication VS OAuth VS HttpClient Authentication 

Tags: security, language-agnostic, oauth, httpclient, http-authentication

Which of the authentication methods above is considered to be better and why? The purpose could be for performing a GET/POST request.

Answer (score 0):

One major benefit is that OAuth works a bit like a valet key - you can authorize an app to work on your behalf without giving it your personal password, you can revoke its access without having to change your own password, etc.

Answer (score -1):

http authentication is not encrypted.  Oauth uses an authentication server to securely log in over https therefore it is more secure.

Comment: HTTP authentication over HTTPS is encrypted, just like OAuth over HTTPS. OAuth over HTTP isn't encrypted, just like HTTP encryption over HTTP.